# Seeking Lenovo G70-70 drivers as .INF, not .EXE

Tags: windows-7, drivers, lenovo-laptop

I have just bought a new Lenovo G70-70 in  Germany and it came with FreeDos. It also has a driver disk, but only for Windows 8.1.

I want to install Windows 7 and when I try the installer asks, in a helpful Microsoft way, for a driver, but doesn't say which one.

No problem, thinks I - I'll just download them all. ***BUT***, I can only find them as `.EXE`s, so I would like to ask where to find them as standard `.INF`s.

Alternatively, could I somehow run those .EXEs on another laptop and obtain the drivers in order to burn them to disc for use in the Windows 7 install?

Comment: Do you know which driver it is looking for?  If not, right click the unknown device and select properties.  Select details tab and under properties find the Hardware ID. Search the Internet with the computer brand and hardware ID.

Comment: If the **installer** is asking for a driver, try disabling UEFI on the laptop and ensure the SATA mode is set to the correct method (might have to change from RAID to AHCI or IDE).

Comment: Sorrt, that didn't help

Comment: I am still wondering why your laptop came with FreeDOS..

Comment: Because, a I said, I bought it in Germany, where we don't have to pay the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bundling_of_Microsoft_Windows#The_.22Windows_tax.22   I was considering using Linux, still might if I can't get those drivers. In which case, why should I be forced to pay for o/s that I don't want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract the drivers, download the [Lenovo drivers](http://support.lenovo.com/ca/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-g-series-laptops/g70-70-laptop?c=1) installation EXEs on another Windows computer, and execute these files.
They are self-unpacking and will unpack the .inf files and full installation media into sub-folders in the default folder of `C:\drivers`.
You can safely answer No when asked at the end whether to install the driver itself,
as the installation files are left in their folder.

However, Windows Update may already contain most of these drivers and is much simpler to use.

The procedure I normally use is :

1. Download [from Lenovo](http://support.lenovo.com/ca/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-g-series-laptops/g70-70-laptop?c=1) all installers to an external disk while giving the downloads meaningful names (all are not required if a second computer is available nearby that is connected to the Internet)
2. Install vanilla Windows 7
3. If the network card is unrecognized, install its driver from the external disk
4. Once connected to the Internet, run Windows Update and install all drivers from the optional section, then boot and run Windows Update again just in case
5. Examine the Device Manager for unknown devices, and install their drivers from the external disk

This is the simplest solution, if the Lenovo drivers are not required for
booting the Windows installation DVD.

If you encounter problems booting the Windows installation, the missing drivers will most probably be one of : The Chipset Driver, the Intel Rapid Storage Technology (IRST) Driver or the Intel Management Engine Interface Driver.
You can extract them as described above.

Comment: I am stuck at point 3 - the Windows install is paused and asking for a driver(it doesn't say which). I only have the .EXes

Comment: Probably needs the Chipset Driver, Intel Rapid Storage Technology (IRST) Driver or Intel Management Engine Interface Driver. But I have found out that installing the .exe on any Windows computer will leave the full drivers  with .inf in the folder `C:\drivers`, where you can get them. Just don't opt for the installation of the driver. Really too simple to believe.

Comment: @Mawg: The only driver you *need* to finish the Windows install would be the storage driver, which you can easily get in .inf format from intel.com. You could also try setting the SATA mode to compatibility in the BIOS if it lets you, then you don't need any driver at all.

Comment: SATA comparability sounded like a great idea. Alas, it did not help :-(

Comment: @Mawg: You might need to extract some Lenovo drivers and add them during the boot when it asks for third-party drivers. I listed above what I see as the minimum set, but no guarantee that you won't need more. You can safely postpone the drivers for unessential devices for until after the installation. Don't play too much with the BIOS, unless the boot doesn't even reach the stage of asking for the drivers.

Comment: That's the whole point of the question - I can find Lenovo drivers, but only as .EXE, not as .INF & when I use 7-zip to extract from the .EXEs I get some files, which the Windows setup doesn't recognize, none of which are .INF

Comment: I wrote above what to do - just execute them on any Windows computer and they unpack themselves.

Answer (score 3):

In most cases you can extract all `.inf` files from `.exe` with some file archiver utility. I use [7-Zip](http://7-zip.org/) for this. Just right click the exe-file and choose `7-Zip > Extract Here`.

Comment: I have upvoted you for what seems like a good approach. It **did** extract some files, but unfortunately Windows 7 install did not recognize them as drivers. There were not any .INF files. I don't understand what is going wrong, but can't award teh answer until I manage to install.